# How to reposition x-axis to be set at 0 in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have a bar chart showing daily profit/loss with a line graph showing running profit. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
daily_profit = [-3.45, -19.1, -3.51, 28.1, 0, -39.18, -8.7]
running_profit = [-3.45, -22.55, -26.06, 2.04, 2.04, -37.14, -45.91]
names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 5))
plt.plot(names, running_profit)
data = pd.DataFrame(daily_profit, index=names, columns=['days'])
data['days'].plot(kind='bar', color=(data['days'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}))
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.title("Weekly profit/loss")
plt.ylabel("GBP (£)")
plt.show()
```

This produces the following graph:
[image: weekly profit graph]

However, I'd like the x-axis to be positioned at y=0 with the days of week also set at y=0. Like so: [image: edited weekly profit graph]

What would the conventional way be to display such information for a weekly profit graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [spines](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/spines_api.html) to center bottom axis. Find the minimum and maximum y values of the data to center the y axis. Then graph. See code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#data
daily_profit = [-3.45, -19.1, -3.51, 28.1, 0, -39.18, -8.7]
running_profit = [-3.45, -22.55, -26.06, 2.04, 2.04, -37.14, -45.91]
names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

#plots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

#spines used to move the bottom axis to the center of the plot
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')

#plots cont.
data = pd.DataFrame(daily_profit, index=names, columns=['days'])
data['days'].plot(kind='bar', color=(data['days'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}))

#find min max of data
yabs_max = abs(max(ax.get_ylim(), key=abs))

#use min max to center 0 y-axis value
ax.set_ylim(ymin=-yabs_max, ymax=yabs_max)

#create plot
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.title("Weekly profit/loss")
plt.ylabel("GBP (£)")
plt.plot(names, running_profit)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]